# Allow element to go out from overflow:hidden container

Tags: html, css

In the example link I have a flex container with some items inside.
On each item there is 'x' that will show the tooltip content (on hover).
I want to apply horizontal scrolling only and display this tooltip out of the main container, how it can be done?

Also, why the container is cuts off when scrolling to the right?

I saw some similar questions here but none of the answers helped.

```css
/* .container {
      position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 99;
    overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: 10.6rem;
        width: 100vw;
} */

.info-bar {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0.8rem 1.6rem 0.8rem 0.8rem;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.info-section {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 1.8rem;
}
.info-section__item {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 8.6rem;
    width: 11.6rem;
    border: solid 1px #ecf0f1;
}
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    top: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
}
.tooltip-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 12rem;
    max-width: 12rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    right: -1rem;
    top: 9.8rem;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    border: solid 1px #ecf0f1;
    color: #515357;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: default;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-content {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="info-bar">
        <div class="info-section">
            <div class="info-section__item">
                <h2>Item</h2>
                <div class="tooltip">
                    x
                    <div class="tooltip-content">
                        tooltip
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info-section__item">
                <h2>Item</h2>
                <div class="tooltip">
                    x
                    <div class="tooltip-content">
                        tooltip
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info-section__item">
                <h2>Item</h2>
                <div class="tooltip">
                    x
                    <div class="tooltip-content">
                        tooltip
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info-section__item">
                <h2>Item</h2>
                <div class="tooltip">
                    x
                    <div class="tooltip-content">
                        tooltip
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info-section__item">
                <h2>Item</h2>
                <div class="tooltip">
                    x
                    <div class="tooltip-content">
                        tooltip
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info-section__item">
                <h2>Item</h2>
                <div class="tooltip">
                    x
                    <div class="tooltip-content">
                        tooltip
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info-section__item">
                <h2>Item</h2>
                <div class="tooltip">
                    x
                    <div class="tooltip-content">
                        tooltip
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info-section__item">
                <h2>Item</h2>
                <div class="tooltip">
                    x
                    <div class="tooltip-content">
                        tooltip
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info-section__item">
                <h2>Item</h2>
                <div class="tooltip">
                    x
                    <div class="tooltip-content">
                        tooltip
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want to apply horizontal scrolling only then do 'overflow-y:hidden'. i didn't quite understand what you want to do with x.

Comment: When you hover on 'x' the tooltip is shown. I want the tooltip come out of the container. Right now it's cutted. That's the problem, I can't use overflow-y:hidden because I need to show the tooltip.

Comment: max-width of  info-section__item greater than tooltip-content
that is max-width 11.6rem  < 12rem

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/ has an approach to solve these kind of situations.

Comment: you can create tooltip dynamically & append/remove it in body on mouseover & mouseout. This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

- For your scrollbar, you can use `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` in your stylesheet.
- Displaying the content outside of the main container : if you're speaking of `.info-bar`, it's not possible, since you gave him an `overflow: auto`, which litteraly means "give me a scroll if content is bigger than you". And a tooltip overflowing a scrollable element seems like a no-no for ux/ui. If you only have an `overflow: visible`, you tooltip clearly overflows the .info-bar.
- why the container is cuts off when scrolling to the right? I don't understand the question.
- your dimensions seems "strange". Are you using `box-sizing : border-box` ?